# Transform origin so animation don't jump

Tags: css, animation, css-transforms

I have created an animated spinner, which is build using "slices of pizza" made of background gradient. The problem is I can't figure out what the origin should be. The animation keeps on jumping.

**See the fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/eqc05bkf/

How can I get rid of the jumping?

HTML:

```
<div class="slices bar">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slices {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
    -moz-animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
    -ms-animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
    -o-animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
    animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
}
.slices.bar div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #CDCDCD 50%, transparent 50%) 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 56px 52px;
    /* container height / 2 */
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, red 50%, transparent 50%) 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
    transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
    transform: rotate(315deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I modified your code a bit. Primarily, I added a container div and simply rotated that. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rr2syj91/)

HTML:

```
<div id='hold'>
    <div class="slices bar">
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
        <div></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slices {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: -31px;
    margin-left: -45px;
    transform-origin: right bottom;
    /*-webkit-animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
    -moz-animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
    -ms-animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
    -o-animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
    animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);*/
}
#hold {
    width: 112px;
    height: 112px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
    -moz-animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
    -ms-animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
    -o-animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
    animation: spin 2.8s infinite steps(8);
}
.slices.bar div {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35px;
    left: 45px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, #CDCDCD 50%, transparent 50%) 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
    transform-origin: 56px 52px;
    /* container height / 2 */
}
@-webkit-keyframes spin {
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes spin {
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes spin {
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}
@keyframes spin {
    to {
        transform: rotate(1turn);
    }
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(1) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    background: linear-gradient(45deg, red 50%, transparent 50%) 0 0;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: 50% 50%;
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(2) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform: rotate(90deg);
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(135deg);
    transform: rotate(135deg);
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(225deg);
    transform: rotate(225deg);
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(7) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
    transform: rotate(270deg);
}
.slices.bar div:nth-child(8) {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(315deg);
    transform: rotate(315deg);
}
```

Comment: Amazing! THX! One more question: Would you know the relationships between the values with respect to the size of the container #hold and .slices? Now the spinner is quite big. I am writting the code in LESS and would like to use few variables to control the component, but some values (i.e. transform-origin in .slices.bar div, ...) seem to me to be just random values.

Comment: OK, I simplified the code and now it seems more clear. http://jsfiddle.net/rr2syj91/2/
But to be a perfectionist, one must mention that the lines are not perfectly aligned with each other. Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: The white lines? To be perfectly honest, not really. I tried fiddling with the slice margins, and that does reposition them, but I found that as soon as one half of the pie was aligned, the other half wasn't, and the peices kept getting further apart. I personally would lay the blame for this on the limits of CSS rendering. Sorry I couldn't be of more help :(

Comment: No problem, I am grateful for ur help anyway! As I use a masking white circle a top of the middle to make it look hollow and resized it to a smaller size, I almost can't see any problem. :)